# Macbook does not use correct version of Node

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

```
I recently installed the latest stable version of node using:

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

nvm use v8.1.0

And when I did nvm list it showed:

       v0.12.13
       v6.9.0
        v7.10.0
->       v8.1.0
         system
default -> stable (-> v8.1.0)
node -> stable (-> v8.1.0) (default)
stable -> 8.1 (-> v8.1.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/boron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.3 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.11.0 (-> N/A)
```

And I manually deleted v6.9.0. Now when I closed my terminal and reopened it, the terminal shows:

N/A: version "6.9.0 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install 6.9.0" to install it before using it.

All I want to use is the latest stable version.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just download the official installer: https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to check .bashrc and .bash_profile when you get such issues. In my ~/.bash_profile, I had the version hardcoded to v6.9.0

so I had

`export NODE_PATH=/Users/[home_directory]/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/lib/node_modules`

and

`nvm use 6.9.0`

I changed it to use the correct versions and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

`nvm use` basically sets up the node version for the current  session.

You should do

```
nvm alias default 8.1
```

Comment: It still gives me: N/A: version "6.9.0 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install 6.9.0" to install it before using it.

Comment: Can u do `nvm uninstall 6.9.0`
This would remove this version from nvm's record.
Then install the newer version and alias it to default

Comment: I got it. In my .bash_profile, I had it hardcoded to 6.9.0. I changed it to 8.1.0 and now it uses the correct version. Thank you so much for your help though.